# how to call a java class from a jsp file

Tags: java, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a java method in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354293/calling-a-java-method-in-jsp)

I need to call a Java method from a jsp page and input values in to that method.

Got correct answer when main function is in the Java class but when it is called by jsp page I can't enter input.

Comment: Generally your would wrap the method in a servlet and call it using values obtained from a form in HTML (e.g. JSP).  I'd say read up on those concepts.  But aside from that, this is too broad a question to be effectively answered on SO.  Voting to close.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354293/calling-a-java-method-in-jsp

Answer (score 3):

First import your class:

```
<%@ page import="mypackage.myclass" %>
```

After that, you can just invoke the method:

```
<% myclass object = new myclass();
   object.invoke();
%>
```

You can also show the details from a return like that:

```
Your name is: ${object.getName()}
```

Comment: Thank you everybody for the replies.... My IDE is netbeans and i have stored my class in WEB-INF/classes but the problem is i don't know the package name. so import tag gives an error

Comment: what do you mean you don't know the package name? Isn't your class? You can find the package in the auto-complete from netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Is the reference to the class present in your jsp code?

```
<% import="your class package" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use useBean tag

```
<jsp:useBean id="cust" class="com.Customer" scope="session"/> 

<%= cust.yourMethodHere() %>
```