# Call java method in JSP file

Tags: java, jsp

I want to call my method getSelectedLayouts in my jsp page, where the method is

```
public Iterable<Layouts> getSelectedLayouts(String Subject){
     Session sess=getCurrentSession();
     return sess.createCriteria(Layouts.class, Subject).list();
 }
```

Inside class LayoutManager. I passed LayoutManager into my jsp page using a Spring Bean

```
<custom:useSpringBean var="layoutManager" bean="LayoutManager">
```

the jsp page asks for the subject

```
<form method="post">
      <label for="subjectName">SubjectName:</label>
      <input type="text" name="subjectName" size="50" id="subjectName">
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search Layout" name="submit">
</form>
```

Which I then pass to

```
<jsp:useBean id="subjectName" class="LayoutManager">
    <c:if test="${param.submit!=null}">

           (here's where I want to call my getSelectedLayouts method)

    </c:if>
```

I've been trying with scriplets, including variations of

```
<jsp:setProperty name="layout" property="*"/>
((LayoutManager)pageContext.getAttribute("layoutManager")).getSelectedLayout((La‌​youts)pageContext.getAttribute("layout"));
```

or just

```
<jsp:setProperty name="layout" property="*"/>
list<Layouts> = LayoutManager.getSelectedLayouts(layout);
```

Where Layouts is my object class

Please tell me if I need to give any other information

Edit: When I try

```
LayoutManager layoutManager = new LayoutManager();
String subjectNa = request.getParameter("subjectName");
Iterable<Layouts> bla = layoutManager.getSelectedLayouts(subjectNa);
```

I get the error list

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /search.jsp at line 72

Iterable<Layouts> waters = layoutManager.getSelectedLayouts(subjectNa);

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.amazon.basalt.examples.octane.tomcat.LayoutManager.getCurrentSession(LayoutManager.java:37)
com.amazon.basalt.examples.octane.tomcat.LayoutManager.getSelectedLayouts(LayoutManager.java:50)
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)

    root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException   com.amazon.basalt.examples.octane.tomcat.LayoutManager.getCurrentSession(LayoutManager.java:37)
com.amazon.basalt.examples.octane.tomcat.LayoutManager.getAllLayouts(LayoutManager.java:68)
org.apache.jsp.search_jsp._jspService(search_jsp.java:221)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
```

Comment: I found a reference here. (The solution here does not uses JSP tags but scriplets )http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354293/calling-a-java-method-in-jsp.

Comment: I've been trying with scriplets, including variations of         ((LayoutManager)pageContext.getAttribute("layoutManager")).getSelectedLayout((Layouts)pageContext.getAttribute("layout"));       or just list<Layouts> = LayoutManager.getSelectedLayouts(layout);

Comment: For second try you have to make the method static. Do post what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution. (If using scriplets is not an issue.)

```
<% 
LayoutManager layoutManager = new LayoutManager();
String subjectName = request.getParameter("subjectName");

layoutManager.getSelectedLayouts(subjectName);
%>
```

Do remember to import the class in the JSP

Comment: I get an java.lang.NullPointerException for  

    layoutManager.getSelectedLayouts(subjectNa);

But its atleast passing my search parameter through now, which is better than before

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use ajax to get the the list of layouts.