# How do I pass my authCode variable from my JSP to a Java class to use in an HTTP call?

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, oauth

I am trying to use a java class in conjunction with a JSP. When the server is started, the user goes to the JSP which redirects them to an authentication form for a third party. After the authentication flow they can fill out their info, press submit and that info gets sent to the server in an HTTP post. The issue I am having is passing variables from my JSP to my java class. I suspect I may need to use a servlet but I wanted to see if there was a way to do this with just a Java class/bean before moving it all into a servlet. I understand I may have to do a call for the variable but I'm not sure how to do this. Any answers or advice would be very helpful! I am a beginner with coding but really want to get this little app up and running. Thank you!

serverFlow.java

```
public class serverFlow {

    public StringBuffer getAccessToken(String redirectUri, String clientId, String clientSecret, String authCode)
            throws IOException {

        // Define base URL
        String baseUrl = "https://idfed.constantcontact.com/as/token.oauth2";

        // Build URL
        String fullUrl = baseUrl + "?code=" + authCode + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri
                + "&grant_type=authorization_code&scope=contact_data";
        URL authorizeUrl = new URL(fullUrl);

        // Open connection
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) authorizeUrl.openConnection();

        // Encode Auth Info
        String credentials = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
        String auth = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());

        // Post Method for CTCT request
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // Add Headers
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);

        // Open input steam
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        // Append each line
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(inputLine);
        }

        // Close the stream
        in.close();

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        serverFlow server = new serverFlow();

    // Print string buffered response of access token, refresh token and authentication type
    // Attempted to use a reqeust but unable to utilize 'reqeust.' is there a way to get the authCode in this Java class from my JSP?
        System.out.println(server.getAccessToken("http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsignup", clientId, clientSecret, authCode));


    }
}
```

signup.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="auth" class="infoClass" scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="auth" property="authCode" />

<html>
<head>
    <title>My Jmml</title>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<h2 style="text-align:center">Contact Information</h2>

<!-- Attempt to get the auth code -->
<%



%>

<jsp:getProperty name="auth" property="authCode"/>

<% if(request.getMethod().equals("GET")){

    // This is where the authCode is generated, how do I get this back over to my serverFlow.jsp?
    String authCode = "";
    try {
        authCode = request.getParameter("code");
        request.setAttribute("authCode", authCode);

        // Verifies it in console
        System.out.println("Here is the auth code: " + authCode);
    }catch(Exception a){
        System.out.println("Could not get Auth Code: " + a);
    }

    }%>

<!-- Input Form -->
<form method='post' action='<% request.getRequestURL(); %>'>
    <div align="center">
        <label>Email Address</label><br /><br />
        <input type='text' name='email' size='50' placeholder="Email" required />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input class="submitbutton" type='submit' value='Submit'/>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>

<!-- Posts info after user presses submit -->
<% if(request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {

    }%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354293/calling-a-java-method-in-jsp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a java method in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354293/calling-a-java-method-in-jsp)