# Access JavaBean object and pass argument to JSP using EL

Tags: jsp, el

I am trying to convert our legacy code into JSTL+EL in our application. I just wanted to know if there's a way to access a JavaBean object and methods with arguments in JSP using EL?

So here's the before and after code.

BEFORE:

```
  <HTML>
<jsp:useBean id="someBean" scope="session" class="package.className" />
<head>
</head>
<BODY>
<p>
<%= ((package.className)session.getAttribute("someBean")).getSomeDataFromBean(request,response) %>
</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Then here's what I want to achieve

```
  <HTML>
    <%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
    <%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix = "fn" %>
    <body> 
       <p> 
         <c:out value="${package.className.getSomeDataFromBean(request,response)}"/> </p>
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

Note that the package class is just a Bean, not a servlet.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2354293/573032) question answer your problem?

Comment: No, i want to avoid scriplets at all costs. I don't have servlets on this, i wanted to explicitly call the Bean to my JSP using JSTL given the sample above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep using `<jsp:useBean>`. It was fine. By default the JSP managed bean is already available by its `id` in EL scope as follows:

```xml
${someBean}
```

So, this should do:

```xml
<c:out value="${someBean.getSomeDataFromBean(pageContext.request, pageContext.response)}" />
```

Note that the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` instances are only available via `${pageContext}`.